# Downloading PDF using Google Data API SDK for .NET v1.8

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs

I'm trying to download PDF file from Google Docs using the .NET libraries.  I'm able to download every other file type but PDFs.  Is downloading PDF supported using the .NET libraries?

I've tried the follow C# code:

```
Stream docStream = request.Download(doc, null);
```

and

```
Stream docStream = request.Dowload(doc,  Document.DownloadType.pdf);
```

and

```
String docUrl = doc.DocumentEntry.Content.Src.ToString();
Uri docUri= new Uri(docUrl);
Stream docStream= request.Service.Query(docUri);
```

Each attempt returns "Execution of request failed" exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today it started working as expected using the following line to download a pdf:

```
Stream docStream = request.Download(doc, null);
```